# HOw to remove SSRS section to ask credentials

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

How to remove this prompt when viewing SSRS report in ASP.net
Can we pass these as two parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would depend on what kind of data provider you have.
Assuming this is an MS SQL data provider:

- Go to the SSRS Report Manager, find your data source and open its properties.
- Then, depending on the authentification method set up in your SQL server and the database, set the appropriate parameters:

  "(o) Credentials stored securely in the report server" - if your server/database require the authorization and you want to provide the user name and password

  "[x] Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source" - check this checkbox if your server/database configured for windows authentification, otherwise leave it unchecked.

  "( ) Windows integrated security" - select this option if you'd like to use the current windows credentials of the report user

  "( ) Credentials are not required" - in case if your data provider and data source don't require the authorization (which is unlikely though)

Hope it helps.

---

Best regards,

Alexey

[www.kudinov.ru](http://www.kudinov.ru)

Answer (score 0):

You could also programmatically set the credentials of the data sources using the ReportViewer.ServerReport.SetDatasourceCredentials method. e.g.

```cs
    // Set credentials
    DataSourceCredentials cred = new DataSourceCredentials();
    ReportDataSourceInfoCollection dataSource = this.ReportViewer.ServerReport.GetDataSources();
    cred.Name = dataSource.First().Name;
    cred.UserId = "userid";
    cred.Password = "password";
    this.ReportViewer.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(new DataSourceCredentials[] { cred });
    this.ReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();

    // Hide credential prompt
    ReportViewer.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;
```