# How to remove SSRS credentials in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623518/how-to-remove-ssrs-section-to-ask-credentials), but I am using VS 2008 and an Oracle database (with Oracle SQL Developer). How do I get rid of the report credentials in VS? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not figure out how to solve this from the database. What I did was, comment out this line of code from the XML of the report:

`<Prompt>Specify a user name and password for data source XXX</Prompt>`

If you have the correct credential info in the `<value>` tag, your report should be loaded with username and password parameters without problems.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to get rid of this is to supply a username and password for the database in question on the reporting server. The URL is usually something like http://localhost/reports. Usually, users created for this type of connection have minimal read-only rights needed for the specific report. The disadvantages to this type of connection is that it's a one-user-fits-all situation. But because of the error message you are getting, it appears that your wish is to supply a specific user name and password rather than use Windows security--which is just fine.

To get here, click Security from the report drop-down list on the main page. Then, click the Credentials stored securely on the report server. Then, here's an issue that get's lots of folks--click the Apply button at the bottom to save the changes. Sometimes the Apply button is not visible and you need to scroll down to click it.

[image]

Now, if you're accessing your report through ReportViewer in VS then the following link may provide some help:

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2012/accessing-ssrs-reports-report-viewer-web-page/

Alternately, you can create or add to a web.config file:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportservercredentials.aspx

p.s. based on our chat, try adding the following to your web.config connection string--if you have one(with the respective user name and password)--if, indeed you're using **Oracle's ODP.net**:

providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=oracle_user;Password=oracle_user_password

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnet-managed-nuget-121021-2405792.txt

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find the "report drop-down list"? I am using Oracle SQL Developer 3.1.07.

Comment: It's for Visual Studio, which you said you were using, which uses SQL Server Express installed with SSRS. The URL should be something like [http://localhost/reports](http://localhost/reports). Unfortunately, VS and ReportingServices can be vastly different from an installation perspective depending on which version it is: [http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/visual-studio-2012-and-sql-server-2012-reporting-services-still-out-sync](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/visual-studio-2012-and-sql-server-2012-reporting-services-still-out-sync)

Comment: but my data source is an Oracle database, I am no sure if the SQL Server Express is going to be used in my case.

Comment: Hmm... as long as you are using SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) or (VS ReportViewer), you'll need to configure it one way or another. i.e. client ==> SSRS ==> Oracle DBMS.